# Cohomology with supports of dualizing sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $Z$ be a closed subvariety of $X$ and $T_{Z/X}$ the relative tangent complex. Possibly I want to assume that $Z \hookrightarrow X$ is a regular embedding, so that $T_{Z/X}$ is just a shift of the normal bundle. Is there a formula relating $H^*_Z(X, \omega_X)$ and $H^*(Z, \omega_Z \otimes T_{Z/X})$?

Such a formula is perhaps suggested by formal analogies with purity. I did computations in some simple cases where $X$ and $Z$ are smooth, and seemed to check out there.